useWatchContractEvent usage
i want to know how i can listen for event send by a smartcontract
const HomeSondage = () => {

    const [ reponses, setReponses] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [ question, setQuestion ] = useState<string>("");
    const [ reponsesPayante, setReponsesPayante] = useState();
    const [ etherValue , setEtherValue ] = useState();
    const [ newSondages, setSondages ] = useState<string[]>([])

    const { data: sondages, isLoading: isSondagesLoading, refetch: refetchSondages } = useReadContract({
        address: homeAddress,
        abi: homeABI,
        functionName: 'sondages',
    })

    const { status, data: creationOK, error: creationError, isPending: creationPending, writeContract } = useWriteContract();
    const creerSondage = async() => {
        console.log("creeation sondage")
        writeContract({
            address: homeAddress,
            abi:homeABI,
            functionName: 'createSondage',
            args:([question, reponses, 10]),
            value: BigInt(1)
        });
    };
    
    const {data , isLoading: ConfirmingCreation, isSuccess: creationSuccess, error: transactionError,   } = useWaitForTransactionReceipt({ 
        hash: creationOK,
    });

    useWatchContractEvent(
    {
        address: homeAddress,
        abi: homeABI,
        eventName: 'Sondagecreation',
        onLogs: logs => console.log(logs)
    });

The smart contract launch an event every time i call a function
There are multiple logs of the event in question, i thought the smart contract launch the event once, and i should have one logs on react side ?

I need to listen for that particular event only on each call of smart contract function, looking for a complete example
